# How can I add a tkinter combobox widget to a gui that also has text entry widgets?

Tags: python, user-interface, combobox, tkinter

I am developing a gui with text entry widgets that regenerate based on the number of a records in a table. I am using a list of fields that are each created as an entry widget. For at least one of these fields, I want to set up a combobox with values for the user to choose from. I've been playing around with adding a combobox to the root (I've just inserted a sample one for now) but it doesn't show up when I run the script. I don't get an error, the gui shows up with all the entry boxes, but not the combobox. Does anyone have any ideas: Here is some of the code:

```
import arcpy, tkMessageBox, ctypes, ttk
from Tkinter import *

mosaicD = r'C:\temp\temp.gdb\mapIndex_MD_test'
mapIndexTbl = r'C:\temp\temp.gdb\mapIndexTestTable'
formFields = ['County', 'Route', 'PMB', 'PME', 'Map_Sheet_Desc', 'HangingFileGroup', 'MapSubSet', 'MapSubSetStatus', 'Shtext', 'Status',
 'SubStatus', 'MapDatum', 'Geo_Referenced_Datum', 'MapScale', 'CAD', 'DrawingDate', 'FileExtention','Original_MrSID_Filename']
fields = arcpy.ListFields(mapIndexTbl)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mosaicD,'name') as cursorB:
        for rowB in cursorB:
            inputValues = []
            def fetch(entries):
                for entry in entries:
                    field = entry[0]
                    text  = entry[1].get()
                    inputValues.append(text)
                root.destroy()

            def makeform(root, fields):
                entries = []
                for field in fields:
                    row = Frame(root)
                    lab = Label(row, width=20, text=field, anchor='w')
                    ent = Entry(row)
                    row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
                    lab.pack(side=LEFT)
                    ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                    entries.append((field, ent))
                return entries

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                root = Tk()
                root.iconbitmap(r'\\sv04docifs5\data5\vol2\Records\GIS\Logos\CT.ico')
                root.geometry('375x650')
                root.wm_title('Enter values for '+rowB[0])
                cities = ('Toronto', 'Ottawa', 'Montreal', 'Vancouver', 'St. John')
                cblist = Frame(root)
                cbp3 = ttk.Labelframe(cblist, text='Pre-defined List')
                cb3 = ttk.Combobox(cbp3, values=cities, state='readonly')
                cb3.current(1)  # set selection
                cb3.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=X)
                # position and display
                cbp3.pack(in_=cblist, side=TOP, pady=5, padx=10)
                ents = makeform(root, formFields)
                root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
                b1 = Button(root, text='Submit',
                      command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
                b1.pack(padx=5, pady=5,anchor=CENTER)
                #b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
                #b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
                root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combobox `cb3` is packed in the frame `cbp3`. That frame is packed in frame `cblist`. Nowhere do you call `pack` or `grid` on `cblist`. Since `cblist` is invisible, so are its children.

Comment: ah thank you! I'm glad it was something simple, I haven't used tkinter a lot